# event listener on Form submit not working

Tags: javascript, events, ninja-forms

On my website, `http://enzo.iotschool.eu/Mixologiststeps/contact-a-mixologist/` there is a form.

I am trying to place an event listener on the submit event to log something but it does not work. Can you tell me what is wrong? Here is my attempt:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', postGift);

function postGift(e) {

  /* add this to prevent submit */
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log('Helloooo there!!!');
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. A website is useless to future visitors since it can be removed or for sure changed to no longer show the issue

Comment: PS: You have TWO forms. Your querySelector will only access the first

Comment: PPS: You seem to be using some kind of form handler (ninjaforms) it is very possible that they have their own way of handling submits

Comment: This is called an X/Y problem. You are using NinjaForms so you need to hook into [their submit events](https://www.google.com/search?q=ninja+form+submit+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector()` returns the first element with the selector provided. When using a generic tag name like `form` as a selector, if the document has more than one form you run the risk of not getting the expected element.

Try instead giving the form an id and querying it using the id selector (`#formid`).

Comment: thanks Jack, I have only one form and  i tried the same on another website (https://nshama.ae/) but it does not work. here you can use the form id: ff_6 and you can see that it wont work, both forms are wordpress plugins

Comment: @Vincenzo As I already said in the comment, you have TWO forms. Your search form in the top right corner is form number 1. Do what Jack suggests

Comment: thanks @mplungjan. I have tried but it still does not work.
can you have a look at a similar form on the website: https://nshama.ae/.
i have used the form id as per you suggestion and still does not work.

document.getElementById('ff_6').addEventListener('submit', postGift);

function postGift(e) {

  /* add this to prevent submit */
  e.preventDefault();
  
  console.log('Helloooo there!!!');
}

Answer (score 1):

Many many issues.

1. `document.querySelector("form")` is accessing the first form on the page. It is not the form you want.
2. The SECOND form on your page is not a standard form. It is produced by the [Ninjaforms](https://ninjaforms.com/) plugin
3. Your form does not have a submit event because the submit button is not a type="submit"
4. The form is generated after load so you need to delegate

Here is an attempt using your RENDERED HTML from your page, but it would be MUCH more useful if you explained what you are trying to do since for now you have an X/Y problem - The code below is a hack. You need to investigate [Ninjaforms Submit event](https://www.google.com/search?q=ninja+form+submit+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("nf-form-3-cont").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.id === "nf-field-18") {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Helloooo there!!!');
    }  
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="nf-form-3-cont" class="nf-form-cont" aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="nf-form-title-3" aria-describedby="nf-form-errors-3" role="form">
  <span id="nf-form-title-3" class="nf-form-title">
        
    </span>
  <div class="nf-form-wrap ninja-forms-form-wrap">
    <div class="nf-response-msg"></div>
    <div class="nf-debug-msg"></div>
    <div class="nf-before-form">
      <nf-section>

      </nf-section>
    </div>
    <div class="nf-form-layout">
      <form>
        <div>
          <div class="nf-before-form-content">
            <nf-section>
              <div class="nf-form-fields-required">Fields marked with an <span class="ninja-forms-req-symbol">*</span> are required</div>

            </nf-section>
          </div>
          <div class="nf-form-content ">
            <nf-fields-wrap>
              <nf-field>
                <div id="nf-field-9-container" class="nf-field-container firstname-container  label-above one-half first ">
                  <div class="nf-before-field">
                    <nf-section>

                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-field">
                    <div id="nf-field-9-wrap" class="field-wrap firstname-wrap nf-fail nf-error" data-field-id="9">



                      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-9" id="nf-label-field-9" class="">First Name <span class="ninja-forms-req-symbol">*</span> </label></div>


                      <div class="nf-field-element">
                        <input type="text" value="" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" id="nf-field-9" name="fname" autocomplete="given-name" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="nf-error-9" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-9" required="" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
                      </div>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-after-field">
                    <nf-section>

                      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>

                      <div id="nf-error-9" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert">
                        <div class="nf-error-msg nf-error-required-error">This is a required field.</div>
                      </div>


                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nf-field>
              <nf-field>
                <div id="nf-field-10-container" class="nf-field-container lastname-container  label-above one-half second ">
                  <div class="nf-before-field">
                    <nf-section>

                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-field">
                    <div id="nf-field-10-wrap" class="field-wrap lastname-wrap" data-field-id="10">



                      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-10" id="nf-label-field-10" class="">Last Name <span class="ninja-forms-req-symbol">*</span> </label></div>


                      <div class="nf-field-element">
                        <input type="text" value="" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" id="nf-field-10" name="lname" autocomplete="family-name" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="nf-error-10" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-10" required="">
                      </div>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-after-field">
                    <nf-section>

                      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>

                      <div id="nf-error-10" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>


                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nf-field>
              <nf-field>
                <div id="nf-field-11-container" class="nf-field-container email-container  label-above ">
                  <div class="nf-before-field">
                    <nf-section>

                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-field">
                    <div id="nf-field-11-wrap" class="field-wrap email-wrap" data-field-id="11">



                      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-11" id="nf-label-field-11" class="">Email  </label></div>


                      <div class="nf-field-element">
                        <input type="email" value="" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" id="nf-field-11" name="email" autocomplete="email" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="nf-error-11" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-11">
                      </div>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-after-field">
                    <nf-section>

                      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>

                      <div id="nf-error-11" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>


                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nf-field>
              <nf-field>
                <div id="nf-field-12-container" class="nf-field-container phone-container  label-above  textbox-container">
                  <div class="nf-before-field">
                    <nf-section>

                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-field">
                    <div id="nf-field-12-wrap" class="field-wrap phone-wrap textbox-wrap" data-field-id="12">



                      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-12" id="nf-label-field-12" class="">Phone  </label></div>


                      <div class="nf-field-element">
                        <input type="tel" value="" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" id="nf-field-12" name="phone" autocomplete="tel" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="nf-error-12" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-12">
                      </div>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-after-field">
                    <nf-section>

                      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>

                      <div id="nf-error-12" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>


                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nf-field>
              <nf-field>
                <div id="nf-field-15-container" class="nf-field-container textarea-container  label-above ">
                  <div class="nf-before-field">
                    <nf-section>

                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-field">
                    <div id="nf-field-15-wrap" class="field-wrap textarea-wrap" data-field-id="15">



                      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-15" id="nf-label-field-15" class="">Details <span class="ninja-forms-req-symbol">*</span> </label></div>


                      <div class="nf-field-element">
                        <textarea id="nf-field-15" name="nf-field-15" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="nf-error-15" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-15" required=""></textarea>
                      </div>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-after-field">
                    <nf-section>

                      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>

                      <div id="nf-error-15" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>


                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nf-field>
              <nf-field>
                <div id="nf-field-16-container" class="nf-field-container checkbox-container  label-right ">
                  <div class="nf-before-field">
                    <nf-section>

                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-field">
                    <div id="nf-field-16-wrap" class="field-wrap checkbox-wrap" data-field-id="16">



                      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-16" id="nf-label-field-16" class="">May We Contact You?  </label></div>


                      <div class="nf-field-element">
                        <input id="nf-field-16" name="nf-field-16" aria-describedby="nf-error-16" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" type="checkbox" value="1" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-16">
                      </div>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-after-field">
                    <nf-section>

                      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>

                      <div id="nf-error-16" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>


                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nf-field>
              <nf-field>
                <div id="nf-field-17-container" class="nf-field-container listselect-container  label-above  list-container">
                  <div class="nf-before-field">
                    <nf-section>

                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-field">
                    <div id="nf-field-17-wrap" class="field-wrap listselect-wrap list-wrap list-select-wrap" data-field-id="17">



                      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-17" id="nf-label-field-17" class="">Best Time to Call  </label></div>


                      <div class="nf-field-element">
                        <select id="nf-field-17" name="nf-field-17" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="nf-error-17" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-17">


                          <option value="morning" selected="selected">Morning</option>


                          <option value="afternoon">Afternoon</option>


                          <option value="evening">Evening</option>

                        </select>
                        <div for="nf-field-17"></div>
                      </div>


                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-after-field">
                    <nf-section>

                      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>

                      <div id="nf-error-17" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>


                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nf-field>
              <nf-field>
                <div id="nf-field-18-container" class="nf-field-container submit-container  label-above  textbox-container">
                  <div class="nf-before-field">
                    <nf-section>

                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-field">
                    <div id="nf-field-18-wrap" class="field-wrap submit-wrap textbox-wrap" data-field-id="18">
                      <div class="nf-field-label"></div>
                      <div class="nf-field-element">
                        <input id="nf-field-18" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element " type="button" value="Submit">
                      </div>
                      <div class="nf-error-wrap"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nf-after-field">
                    <nf-section>

                      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>

                      <div id="nf-error-18" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>


                    </nf-section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nf-field>
            </nf-fields-wrap>
          </div>
          <div class="nf-after-form-content">
            <nf-section>

              <div id="nf-form-errors-3" class="nf-form-errors" role="alert">
                <nf-errors>
                  <nf-section>
                    <div class="nf-error-msg nf-error-field-errors">Please correct errors before submitting this form.</div>
                  </nf-section>
                </nf-errors>
              </div>
              <div class="nf-form-hp">
                <nf-section>
                  <label for="nf-field-hp-3" aria-hidden="true">
        If you are a human seeing this field, please leave it empty.
        <input id="nf-field-hp-3" name="nf-field-hp" class="nf-element nf-field-hp" type="text" value="">
    </label>
                </nf-section>
              </div>
            </nf-section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="nf-after-form">
      <nf-section>

      </nf-section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed answer. I am simply trying to console log something when the form is submitted from the developer console. It has always worked with the Dom event listener submit. In fact I am running the code from the console of chrome

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.google.com/search?q=ninja+form+submit+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com